# Deriving values based on result of the query and grouping the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a sql where I am trying to pull out information of the status of the courses the user has enrolled. I am trying to return single record for each user. Two fields in the select list would derive the value in the following manner

CourseResultStatusId - 
If the status of all the courses is passed then return the status as passed otherwise.
If any status is fail, the overall status is fail.
If any of the status is expired, then overall status is expired.
If any of the status is in-progress then overall status is in-progress

ExpiryDateTime - Training expiring (nearest date)
I need to apply the following logic on courses he has been assigned.
cr.ExpiryDateTime > GetDate() and cr.ExpiryDateTime <= dateadd(dd,30,getdate()) )

If you see below , the query I have written so far pulls the courses that each user has been enrolled but it is not a cumulative result. Do I need to group, if yes would need help.

```
DECLARE @Rep1 INT;
SET @Rep1 = 13119;

        SELECT      
                     cr.[CourseID]
                    ,cr.[UserID]
                    ,u.[Code]
                    ,u.[DisplayName]
                    ,t.[Name]
                    ,cr.[CourseResultStatusID]  AS [CourseResultStatusID]
                    ,crs.[Description]          AS [CourseResultStatusDescription]
                    ,c.[PointsRequired]
                    ,cr.[ExpiryDateTime]


        FROM        [training].[CourseResult] cr
        INNER JOIN  [training].[Course] c
            ON      cr.[CourseID] = c.[ID] and c.[IsOptional] = 0 -- and cr.ExpiryDateTime > GetDate() and cr.ExpiryDateTime <= dateadd(dd,30,getdate()) 
        INNER JOIN  [training].[CourseResultStatus] crs
            ON      cr.[CourseResultStatusID] = crs.[ID]
        INNER JOIN org.RepresentativeTierHistory rth on rth.RepresentativeID = cr.[UserID] and GetDate() between rth.StartDate and rth.EndDate
        INNER JOIN  org.tier t on t.ID = rth.TierID
        LEFT JOIN   [org].[User] u
            ON      u.[ID] = cr.[UserID]

      WHERE cr.[UserID] IN (
        SELECT hd.DescendantId FROM org.HierarchyDescendant hd WHERE hd.RepresentativeId = @Rep1 UNION ALL SELECT @Rep1 -- for management exchange info
      )
      order by UserID
```

The result of the query is as follows. I have circled to show you records that belong to a particular user and the columns that I am interested in  . I need help in getting single record for each user based on the of logic that I mentioned above.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you can implement the priorization rules on the overall result of each user using conditional aggregation.

Starting from your existing query, the logic would be:

```
select
    cr.[UserID],
    case
        when min(case when crs.[Description] = 'Complete' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
            then 'Complete'
        when max(case when crs.[Description] = 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
            then 'Fail'
        when max(case when crs.[Description] = 'Expired' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
            then 'Expired'
        when max(case when crs.[Description] = 'In Progress' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
            then 'In Progress'
    end as ResultStatus
from ...
where ...
group by cr.[UserID]
```

As for the date filtering logic, you should be able to implement it directly in the `where` clause.

It is possible that other parts of your query can be optimized - you might want to ask a new question for this, providing proper sample data and desired results.