# Group by clause not returning the desired result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that will pull the status of the courses enrolled for each user. I need to display a single record for that user that will represent the overall status of the courses. As you can see in the query below, it uses case statement to decide the prioritisation of the status. I have tried to use a `group by` clause but it still shows all the courses in the resultset. Could someone let me know what am I doing wrong in the query

```
DECLARE @Rep1 INT;
SET @Rep1 = 13119;

        SELECT      
                     cr.[CourseID]
                    , cr.[UserID]
                    ,u.[Code]
                    ,u.[DisplayName]
                    ,t.[Name]
                    ,cr.[CourseResultStatusID]  AS [CourseResultStatusID]
                     ,case
                        when min(case when crs.[Description] = 'Complete' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
                            then 'Complete'
                        when max(case when crs.[Description] = 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
                            then 'Fail'
                        when max(case when crs.[Description] = 'Expired' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
                            then 'Expired'
                        when max(case when crs.[Description] = 'In Progress' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
                            then 'In Progress'
                    end as [CourseResultStatusDescription]
                    ,c.[PointsRequired]
                    ,cr.[ExpiryDateTime]


        FROM        [training].[CourseResult] cr
        INNER JOIN  [training].[Course] c
            ON      cr.[CourseID] = c.[ID] and c.[IsOptional] = 0 -- and cr.ExpiryDateTime > GetDate() and cr.ExpiryDateTime <= dateadd(dd,30,getdate()) 
        INNER JOIN  [training].[CourseResultStatus] crs
            ON      cr.[CourseResultStatusID] = crs.[ID]
        INNER JOIN org.RepresentativeTierHistory rth on rth.RepresentativeID = cr.[UserID] and GetDate() between rth.StartDate and rth.EndDate
        INNER JOIN  org.tier t on t.ID = rth.TierID
        LEFT JOIN   [org].[User] u
            ON      u.[ID] = cr.[UserID]

      WHERE cr.[UserID] IN (
        SELECT hd.DescendantId FROM org.HierarchyDescendant hd WHERE hd.RepresentativeId = @Rep1 UNION ALL SELECT @Rep1 -- for management exchange info
      )
      group by  cr.[CourseID], cr.[UserID], u.[Code], u.[DisplayName], t.[Name], [CourseResultStatusID],c.[PointsRequired],cr.[ExpiryDateTime]
```

The result of the query is below. As you can see there are 24 records. It is currently showing all the 6 courses per user. It should ideally only only 4 records.

[image: roup b]

REsultset that I am looking for

[image]

Comment: Well, if you want one row per user, then remove the other columns from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses - as showned in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140882/deriving-values-based-on-result-of-the-query-and-grouping-the-data)...

Comment: But I need the other columns as well as I need to display it in my client application 

Comment: Do I need to write a sub query ?

Comment: please show us the result that you want - as tabular text (no images).

Comment: I have updated the post. As you can see I have done it for one employee. Its a single record for that employee. It would be similar for other employees as well

Comment: As you mentioned in the previous post that expiry logic will fit in the where clause. Could you show me that as well please. I have currently commented that code in the where logic